# Захваты с инициализатором и без, лямбда функции С++

Tags: c++, lambda

В чем разница между этими двумя предикатами:

```
auto predicate = [z = x + y] (int i) { return i > z; };
auto predicate = [x, y] (int i) { return i > (x + y); };
```

Comment: По-моему, никакой. Разве что в месте вычисления суммы, но на функциональность это никак не влияет.

Comment: Я не уверен, насколько хорошо вторая лямбда соптимизируется.

Comment: Найдите различие: https://godbolt.org/z/rPE9b6M4Y  (Оно есть!)

Comment: @Chorkov Ну разве что в размере захватываемого :) В том же VC++ отличий куда больше. Но похоже прав первый оратор, что функционально это одно и то же.